# SQL Azure workers percentage hitting limit and causing failed requests

Tags: azure-sql-database

One of our databases in Azure hit its max number of Workers (requests) which caused the database to fail any requests for about the next minute. It then recovered without any input from us, the Workers Percentage being reported in Azure Metrics for the database returned to normal at around 15%.

I have looked into the metrics for our API that serves the database and it had no increase in HTTP requests beyond the amount it would normally receive.

According to the SQL Query Store, some queries took longer around the time of this issue but nothing to help identify the cause.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could cause this or anything to look into to help identify the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no SSMS UI for this, you can use the data you found in the query store to look up into this extra table that we recently added - it tracks the most common wait types per query/plan bucket for you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

It also categorizes them (roughly) for you to help you understand if it is caused by CPU, IO, etc.

Please take a look and I hope that helps you peel the onion one more level on your performance issue.

Comment: Hi Conor, that table has been quite useful it looks like requests were waiting on CPU and Memory. Didn't seem like that in the azure metrics but I am going to up the power of the DB and continue monitoring. Thanks for the assistance.